# async foreach call not synchronous node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js

I want to loop through some predictions of participants and calculate some points.
To know how many points a player gets I need to make a call to mongodb (using mongoose). Then I want to save the scores per participant (will do that later)

I'm using this async module: http://caolan.github.io/async/

```js
var calculateTeamPredictionsPerRound = function (roundId) {
  var roundScores = [];

  predictions.find({}, {}).exec(function (err, predictions) {
    console.log("predictions length: " + predictions.length)
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    async.each(predictions,
      function (prediction) {
        var teamScores = [];
        console.log("team length: " + prediction.Team.length + "deelnemer: " + prediction.Participant.Name)

        async.forEach(prediction.Team, function (player,callback) {
          console.log("for player: " + player.PlayerName + "participant: " + prediction.Participant.Name);

          teamScore.findOne({ RoundId: roundId, 'Player.Id': player.Id }, { Player: { $elemMatch: { Id: player.Id } } }).exec(function (err, player) {
            console.log(player.Player[0].Name);
            var playerScore = new Object;
            playerScore.Name = player.Player[0].Name;
            playerScore.Team = player.Player[0].Team;
            playerScore.Won = setWinScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.Draw = setDrawScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.Played = setPlayedScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.RedCard = setRedCardScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.YellowCard = setYellowCardScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.Assist = setAssistScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.Goals = setGoalScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.OwnGoal = setOwnGoalScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.TotalScore = playerScore.Won + playerScore.Draw + playerScore.Played + playerScore.RedCard + playerScore.YellowCard + playerScore.Assist + playerScore.OwnGoal + playerScore.Goals;
            teamScores.push(playerScore)
          });
          callback();       
        });

      });
  });
};
```

When I run this code the console shows me this:

```
team length: 11 participant: test   
for player: a participant: test  
for player: b participant: test  
for player: c participant: test  
for player: d participant: test  
for player: e participant: test  
for player: f participant: test  
for player: g participant: test  
for player: h participant: test  
for player: i participant: test  
for player: j participant: test  
for player: k participant: test  
team length: 11participant: test2  
for player: a participant: test2  
for player: b participant: test2  
for player: c participant: test2  
for player: d participant: test2  
for player: e participant: test2  
for player: f participant: test2  
for player: g participant: test2  
for player: h participant: test2  
for player: i participant: test2  
for player: j participant: test2  
for player: k participant: test  
a  
b  
c  
d  
e  
f  
g  
h  
i  
j  
k  
a  
b  
c  
d  
e  
f  
g  
h  
i  
j  
k
```

But I want:

```
team length: 11participant: test  
for player: a participant: test  
a  
for player: b participant: test  
b
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `async.forEach` method you use a `.findOne()` method which is also asynchronous.

The execution order is:

1. console.log("for player: " + player.PlayerName + "participant: " +    prediction.Participant.Name);
2. findOne()
3. callback()

You call callback() of the async function without waiting for the callback of findOne(), which is `function (err, player) {...}`.

Move callback() inside of `function (err, player) {...}` to wait for the findOne() to execute before finishing the async task.

```
teamScore.findOne({ RoundId: roundId, 'Player.Id': player.Id }, { Player: { $elemMatch: { Id: player.Id } } }).exec(function (err, player) {
            console.log(player.Player[0].Name);
            var playerScore = new Object;
            playerScore.Name = player.Player[0].Name;
            playerScore.Team = player.Player[0].Team;
            playerScore.Won = setWinScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.Draw = setDrawScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.Played = setPlayedScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.RedCard = setRedCardScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.YellowCard = setYellowCardScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.Assist = setAssistScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.Goals = setGoalScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.OwnGoal = setOwnGoalScore(player.Player[0]);
            playerScore.TotalScore = playerScore.Won + playerScore.Draw + playerScore.Played + playerScore.RedCard + playerScore.YellowCard + playerScore.Assist + playerScore.OwnGoal + playerScore.Goals;
            teamScores.push(playerScore)
            callback();  
          });         
        });
```

Also, instead of `teamScores.push(playerScore)` you can `callback(playerScore)`, and then give a final callback to `async.forEach`, which will be called with an array of all playerScores, when all the tasks are completed.

If async.forEach is [this](https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-sync-async-foreach) module, I'm not sure why you need it, since all of your tasks are asynchronous. It doesn't automatically make `teamScore.findOne()` synchronous, you still have to specify an async callback with `var done = this.async();` and call it when findOne() is done, but you can also just use the regular async.each()instead.

Comment: Ok, I was just confused, because async.forEach is not part of that module, only async.each. Solution should be the same.

Comment: `forEach` is an alias of `each`